# Undefined getUserId() function in MVCTable

Tags: php, user-interface, frameworks, atk4

I use atk 4.1.2. I found a problem while I tried to Insert/Update my Model. It seems like because I added two fields in my table, i.e. : `created_by` and `updated_by`.

I found these lines caused the problem in MVCTable.php:

```
if (isset($this->fields['created_by']))
            $this->dsql('modify',false)->set('created_by',$this->api->getUserId());

if (isset($this->fields['updated_by']))
            $this->dsql('modify',false)->set('updated_by',$this->api->getUserId());
```

The method `$this->api->getUserId()` is not defined anywhere. I don't know whether this same problem occurs for the previous atk versions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's a bit of legacy code which I haven't cleaned up yet. Please delete those lines manually and they will not be there in further versions.

https://github.com/atk4/atk4-addons/commit/e3b2379

Comment: OK, I'll remove them. Thank you.